# Regarding malware and hardware

Tags: malware, hardware

Bit of a weird one, hope this is the appropriate venue:

I've just purchased some [Ethernet-over-power adapters](http://www.dlink.com.au/home-solutions/powerline-av500-passthrough-network-starter-kit) that were returned to and repackaged by a brick and mortar retailer. I'm trying to be more vigilant with security recently and was wondering: should I be concerned in at all that these devices could have been loaded with malware or something nasty?

I know this may be paranoia but I am sharing this internet connection with others and am mindful of something that will be connected directly to the router.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thank god they have that diagram on the page you linked, otherwise I would have thought this was a huge scam product. I thought it claimed to turn outlets into internet sources, and was very confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any device that you are using *can* be malicious; and what you bought can be full of spy tools made by your government especially to spy on *you*. You don't know. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

You should ask yourself whether you can trust the manufacturer and the retailer.

I honestly think you should not worry about that; or start worrying about *all* the devices you are using. ([firewalls](http://www.wired.com/2015/12/juniper-networks-hidden-backdoors-show-the-risk-of-government-backdoors/), [USB keys](http://kukuruku.co/hub/diy/usb-killer), [bluetooth headsets](http://trifinite.org/blog/archives/2005/07/introducing_the.html), etc.)

But remember that at some point, you have to trust in something.